# JAVA: Using select in the client side

Tags: java, sockets

I want to connect a client to many servers and receive the first answer from one of them. So I decided to use select. I created a socket with each server and I registered those sockets in a selector. But it didn't work. Here's where there is a problem in my code:

```
        Selector selector = Selector.open();//
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<serveurs.size();i++)//I have an arraylist of servers
        {
            Socket s=new Socket(serveurs.get(i).getIP(),port);//creating a socket with the server number i

            sc=s.getChannel();//here's the problem: sc is null
            sc.configureBlocking(false);//exception here because sc=null
            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);//register the socket channel to recieve data form the server

        }
        selector.select();
        // reading data in the socket registered in the selector
```

So what can I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing the book ["TCP/IP Sockets in Java, 2nd Edition"](http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780080568782&pagename=search) came across playing with time server and client. The small demo code for [TcpTimeClient.java](https://gist.github.com/kenix/6cdb7bd52fafe3498061) basically does what you described.

Problems I can see in your code:

1. To get a SocketChannel, use SocketChannel.open(). The JavaDoc of Socket.getChannel() tells what to do.
2. Use interest OP_CONNECT to try all connections first, then use interest OP_READ to find the winner.

Concerns depending on the application protocol:

1. Avoid deadlock, e.g. if server expects reading a message from client before responding and client just waits for response without writing the message first.
2. The first winner might not be the best, consider any other QoS approaches. Or keep all connections open and switch if necessary.